# Display thumbnail images in a grid with expanding preview

Tags: javascript

i'm struggle with this code from a week now and i cannot find how to display multi images associated with the large image in the preview area. The code i use is the one from codrops http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

The code works fine but with each large images i want to display beside the large image some other images.

The problem is i'm not so good with Javascript but here wnat i understand

In the index.html page we found a list of image

like this

```
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-title="Kuche" data-store="Reitmans" data-avatarsrc="images/userImg/kuche.png" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot."> 
                        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg" data-title="Megane" data-store="Belle et Rebelle" data-avatarsrc="images/userImg/megane.png" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/3.jpg" data-title="Dandelion horseradish" data-description="Cabbage bamboo shoot broccoli rabe chickpea chard sea lettuce lettuce ricebean artichoke earthnut pea aubergine okra brussels sprout avocado tomato.">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/4.jpg" data-title="Azuki bean" data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="img04"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/2.jpg" data-title="Veggies sunt bona vobis" data-description="Komatsuna prairie turnip wattle seed artichoke mustard horseradish taro rutabaga ricebean carrot black-eyed pea turnip greens beetroot yarrow watercress kombu.">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

What i understand is the Javascript use the `<img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>` to do the grid and it use the a href attributs to generate the preview area.

like this :

```
    Preview.prototype = {
    create : function() {
        // create Preview structure:
        this.$title = $( '<h4></h4>' );
        this.$store = $( '<h5></h5>' );
        this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
        this.$href = $( '<a href="#" target="_blank">Visit website</a>' );
        this.$addtext = $( '<span class="og-addtext">Add me in<br>your staff</span>' );
        this.$userimage = $( '<p></p>' ).append( this.$loading );
        this.$add = $( '<span class="og-add"></span>' );
        this.$top = $('<div class="og-detailstop"></div>').append( this.$userimage, this.$title, this.$store, this.$addtext, this.$add );
        this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$top);
        this.$soc = $( '<div class="og-soc"></div>' )
        this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
        this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
        this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
        this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
        this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
        // append preview element to the item
        this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
        // set the transitions for the preview and the item
        if( support ) {
            this.setTransition();
        }
    },
    update : function( $item ) {

        if( $item ) {
            this.$item = $item;
        }

        // if already expanded remove class "og-expanded" from current item and add it to new item
        if( current !== -1 ) {
            var $currentItem = $items.eq( current );
            $currentItem.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
            this.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
            // position the preview correctly
            this.positionPreview();
        }

        // update current value
        current = this.$item.index();

        // update preview´s content
        var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
            eldata = {
                href : $itemEl.attr( 'href' ),
                largesrc : $itemEl.data( 'largesrc' ),
                title : $itemEl.data( 'title' ),
                store : $itemEl.data( 'store' ),
                avatarsrc : $itemEl.data( 'avatarsrc' ),
                addtext : $itemEl.data( 'addtext' ),
                add : $itemEl.data( 'add' ),
                description : $itemEl.data( 'description' )
            };

        this.$title.html( eldata.title );
        this.$store.html( eldata.store );
        this.$description.html( eldata.description );
        this.$href.attr( 'href', eldata.href );

        var self = this;

        // remove the current image in the preview
        if( typeof self.$largeImg != 'undefined' ) {
            self.$largeImg.remove();
        }

        // preload large image and add it to the preview
        // for smaller screens we don´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
        if( self.$fullimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
            this.$loading.show();
            $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                var $img = $( this );
                if( $img.attr( 'src' ) === self.$item.children('a').data( 'largesrc' ) ) {
                    self.$loading.hide();
                    self.$fullimage.find( 'img' ).remove();
                    self.$largeImg = $img.fadeIn( 350 );
                    self.$fullimage.append( self.$largeImg );
                }
            } ).attr( 'src', eldata.largesrc ); 
        }

        if( typeof self.$userImg != 'undefined' ) {
            self.$userImg.remove();
        }

        // preload user image and add it to the preview
        // for smaller screens we don´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
        if( self.$userimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
            this.$loading.show();
            $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                var $imgUser = $( this );
                if( $imgUser.attr( 'src' ) === self.$item.children('a').data( 'avatarsrc' ) ) {
                    self.$loading.hide();
                    self.$userimage.find( 'user' ).remove();
                    self.$userImg = $imgUser.fadeIn( 350 );
                    self.$userimage.append( self.$userImg );
                }
            } ).attr( 'src', eldata.avatarsrc );    
        }


    },
```

So here where i'm stuck

I want to acheive something like this

```
    <ul>
    <li>
                        <a   href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-  title="Kuche" data-store="Reitmans" data-avatarsrc="images/userImg/kuche.png" data-  description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko   coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot."> 
                            <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg"   alt="img01"/>

   <img src="images/items/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
   <img src="images/items/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
   <img src="images/items/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
                        </a>                    
   </li>
   </ul>
```

Adding some images associated with the large image and displayed beside the large image in a array. But if i just add the images like this it display the images in the grid (i don't want that) and i cannot figure how to add those associated images and display them only in the preview area.

If anyone can give me a tip, trick or hack to find a way to achieve that i will be really greatfull.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Preview object seems to use the `data-largesrc` attribute's value as the source for the large image in the details section, however that large image will only get displayed on larger screens, because the large image's container (`div.og-fullimg`) will be hidden using media queries on small resolution screens.

By knowing that, a solution that doesn't require you to modify the plugin's code would be to create a new image that contains all the small images that you want to display and pass the path of that image as value for the `data-largesrc` attribute.

However, you could also implement a new feature where a `data-images attribute could be set and handled by the plugins code.

E.g. `<a href="..." data-img-collection="img1.png,img2.png,img3.png">`

Comment: Hi plalx, i try to figure your first solution 

"By knowing that, a solution that doesn't require you to modify the plugin's code would be to create a new image that contains all the small images that you want to display and pass the path of that image as value for the data-largesrc attribute."

the data-largesrc already as a attribute is the link for the large size so i'm not quit understand your solution can you develop a bit so i can try it.

For the second solution look insterestiing i will try it.

Really appreciat your answer.

Regards

Comment: "how to display multi images associated with the large image in the preview area"

@user2340683, Since the image referenced by the `data-largesrc` attribute is used in the preview area, if you change that to point to an image that contains multiple images it will give you the desired result.

Comment: No, doesn't work with <a href="..." data-img-collection="img1.png,img2.png,img3.png"> work only if i put 1 image but if i put more it show nothing.

Comment: @user2340683, Well can you show how you changed the code? It won't work without the correct implementation...

Comment: Hi plalx i just add the way i change the code by answering my question. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i done

```
<li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" data-largesrc="images/1.jpg" data-title="Kuche" data-store="Reitmans" data-avatarsrc="images/userImg/kuche.png" data-description="Social icons here" data-items="images/itemsImg/1.jpg"> 
                        <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I add `data-items="images/itemsImg/1.jpg">` if i try with multi image like this `data-items="images/itemsImg/1.jpg, images/itemsImg/2.jpg, images/itemsImg/3.jpg">` it doesn't work (display no image at all. But with one image i'm able to display it.

What i hack in the .js file is the code using to display the largeimage

```
// remove the current image in the preview
        if( typeof self.$largeImg != 'undefined' ) {
            self.$largeImg.remove();
        }

        // preload large image and add it to the preview
        // for smaller screens we don´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
        if( self.$fullimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
            this.$loading.show();
            $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                var $img = $( this );
                if( $img.attr( 'src' ) === self.$item.children('a').data( 'largesrc' ) ) {
                    self.$loading.hide();
                    self.$fullimage.find( 'img' ).remove();
                    self.$largeImg = $img.fadeIn( 350 );
                    self.$fullimage.append( self.$largeImg );
                }
            } ).attr( 'src', eldata.largesrc ); 
        }
```

I copy and paste the code but to display the data-items image see below

```
if( typeof self.$itemImg != 'undefined' ) {
                self.$itemImg.remove();
            }

            // preload items image and add it to the preview
            // for smaller screens we don´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
            if( self.$itemsimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
                this.$loading.show();
                $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                    var $imgItem = $( this );
                    if( $imgItem.attr( 'src' ) === self.$item.children('a').data( 'items' ) ) {
                        self.$loading.hide();
                        self.$itemsimage.find( 'itemsImg' ).remove();
                        self.$itemImg = $imgItem.fadeIn( 350 );
                        self.$itemsimage.append( self.$itemImg );
                    }
                } ).attr( 'src', eldata.items );    
            }
```

With this code i can display the image in the data-items attributes but not if they have more than 1 image.

Any help will be appreciate.